# How to get back the same values from a list after taking inverse?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In the following program I have a numpy array t.I divide it by one to get J values. Now after taking the inverse I want to get back same array t. I tried to do this in the following code but when I print t and T_list they give me different values. I want exactly the same values of t as in the beginning.

```
`t= np.linspace(1,4,10)
print(t)
J_values =[]
for i in range(len(t)):
    j= 1.0/t[i]
    J_values.append(j)

print(J_values)
T_list =[]
for i in range(len(J_values)):
    T=1.0/J_values[i]
    T_list.append(T)
print(T_list)`
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code example seems to run fine. The values in `t` match the values in `T_list` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the great things about NumPy arrays is that you rarely have to use loops to manipulate them. Inverting the values of `t` can be done like this:

```
t = np.linspace(1, 4, 10)
J_values = 1.0 / t
```

Getting the original values back is then:

```
T_list = 1.0 / J_values
```

Comment: But why it does not work when my J_values is a list?

Comment: because the functionality (which is called "broadcasting") that makes it possible to write this without using a loop is implemented in the numpy.ndarray class. So it only works with objects of this type. A plain Python list does not implement this functionality, so with those, a loop is needed.